# How to create and maintain patch on Debian package?

Tags: package-management, patch

I want to patch on Trac package. I know how to patch and rebuild the package, but there are some things I don't understand very well.

My patch is something dangerous and not likely to commit back to the community. So, let me just say, it's a very private patch. But, I want my patch keep working when the Ubuntu packages upgrade. (Should I `apt-get source trac` and move my patch to the new version of source directory each time the `Trac` upgrades?)

I see there is a `patch/` directory (many using `quilt` I guess) in `debian/`, but I don't know how to use it? Will `debuild` automatic apply all patches in the `patch/` directory? And what about `dpkg-buildpackage`? Is there some environ variables to control the selection of patches to apply?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the [Patches to Packages](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/patches-to-packages.html) section in the [Packaging Guide](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/), for a better understanding how it works you should read the entire guide.

Answer (score 2):

Even though this is an old question, it is actual still. Thus I'd like to add some up-to-date information to it.
The other answer bluntly links to manual whereas it would be helpful to point exactly the necessary information.

From [the manual mentioned](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/patches-to-packages.html) relevant part is

> 8.4. Upgrading to New Upstream Versions
>
> To upgrade to the new version, you can use `bzr merge-upstream` command

But this is Ubuntu-specific.

Alternatively one can use `apt-src`. [Manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/apt-src.1p.html) says:

> -p, --patch
>
> Try to patch local changes into new source tree when upgrading. On
>
> by default, use --no-p to disable.  Configuration Item:
>
> APT::Src::Patch.

For this to work you need to install `apt-src`, with `sudo apt-get install apt-src` for instance.

Another possibility is to use `quilt`. Excerpt from paragraph "5.26. patches/*" from [Debian New Maintainers' Guide](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#patches) follows:

> When anyone (including yourself) provides a patch foo.patch to the source later, modifying a 3.0 (quilt) source package is quite simple:
>
> $ dpkg-source -x gentoo_0.9.12.dsc
>
> $ cd gentoo-0.9.12
>
> $ dquilt import ../foo.patch
>
> $ dquilt push
>
> $ dquilt refresh
>
> $ dquilt header -e
>
> ... describe patch