# How one can create an installer for custom keyboard layout

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout, packaging, xkb

I've managed to create a custom keyboard layout for [my language](https://github.com/theunibal/unibal-linux).

Now that the keyboard is in a state that I can share it. I don't know how to make it a redistributable package.

Answer (score 7):

To add it to the official `xkeyboard-config` package, you would develop it as a patch for the [`xkeyboard-config` package](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/XKeyboardConfig/).  See their [code contribution guide](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/XKeyboardConfig/Rules/); contributed layouts are made by patches on their bug tracker.  You can clone the upstream repository with:

```
git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/xkeyboard-config
```

- From a quick glance at your layout, I think you need to add the `default` keyword to the stanza definition (`default xkb_symbols "basic"`), to declare that layout the default for that file.  Your file itself would be put in the `symbols` directory.
- In addition to your new layout file, you'll need to add it to the rules templates (`rules/base.xml.in` or possibly `rules/base.extras.xml.in` -- the `rules/evdev.xml` file will be generated from the same template).
- Doublecheck the project documentation for other specifics that I might have missed.

---

You could also add that patch to the [Ubuntu source package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/uk/source/yakkety/xkeyboard-config) apply it with the standard dpkg build tools.  This would allow you to distribute your modifications to other Ubuntu users with minimal difficulty.  See questions like [How to create and maintain patch on Debian package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19070/how-to-create-and-maintain-patch-on-debian-package) for more specifics.

Comment: Can your custom package-approach of the upstream one be used in this challenge: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/346073/16920 ?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 sure.  i'd strongly advise making your layout a new variant, rather than changing an existing one, but for personal use it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your keyboard layout as a Debian package. This will create a `.deb` file which can be installed from the command line with `sudo apt install -f ./my-file.deb` or just by double-clicking the file in the file explorer.

I've done this and have published the work [on GitHub](https://github.com/geajack/xkeyboard-franco-polish). That repository contains really all you need to do this, but in the interest of having a self-contained answer here, I'll give an outline of the process.

Step zero, learn [how to make a keyboard layout](http://people.uleth.ca/~daniel.odonnell/Blog/custom-keyboard-in-linuxx11). You basically have to modify some configuration files in `/usr/share/X11/xkb`.

Then, learn [how to make a Debian package](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=910717). Our package's job is basically going to be to just modify the right files in the aforementioned `xkb` directory. However, if you try to do this, you'll find [as I did](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1173862/can-i-create-an-uninstallable-debian-package-which-overwrites-another-packages/1173906#1173906) that `dpkg` yells at you for trying to overwrite another package's files. You will need to get around this using [diversions](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ap-pkg-diversions.html).