# How can I package a custom keyboard layout for personal use?

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout, contributing

I've created a custom keyboard layout, but I want to use it on multiple computers. How can I package up my custom layout in such a way that I can easily install it on other computers?

I've begun following the steps outlined [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764248/how-one-can-create-an-installer-for-custom-keyboard-layout), but there are two problems with the accepted answer.

1. The answer appears to be obsolete, since Bugzilla now gives me the error [" Sorry, entering a bug into the product xkeyboard-config has been disabled."](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=xkeyboard-config).
2. The answer is not detailed enough for me. I've made what I think are the correct modifications to the git repository, but now what? The answer just says to use "standard dpkg build tools", but I don't really know what that means.

Comment: You can build xkeyboard-config with your modifications in a PPA.