# Can I create an uninstallable debian package which overwrite's another package's files?

Tags: package-management

I'm trying to create a Debian package which installs a custom keyboard layout. In order to do this, you need to modify two files in `/usr/share/X11/xkb`. So my package just includes the new versions of those files. When I try to install it, dpkg complains about conflicts with the xkeyboard package and won't let me. I'm aware that I could use `--force-overwrite` to install it anyway, but I'm worried about uninstalling the package later. I'd like to create a Debian package with the following behavior:

1. When installed, overwrites files belonging to another package.
2. When uninstalled, files return to the state they were in before the installation.

Is this possible?

Comment: Using post-install [*postinst*] & removal [*postrm*] scripts to do what you want is my immediate reaction .. but i'm unsure if there will be issues from it's use...   You can think that through..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to have dpkg not overwrite a file when it reinstalls the package it belongs to, and to have it put the file from the package somewhere else instead.

This can be used locally to override a package’s version of a file, or by one package to override another’s version (or provide a wrapper for it).

There is a diversion list, which is read by dpkg, and updated by a special program dpkg-divert. Please see dpkg-divert(8) for full details of its operation.

When a package wishes to divert a file from another, it should call dpkg-divert in its preinst to add the diversion and rename the existing file. For example, supposing that a smailwrapper package wishes to install a wrapper around /usr/sbin/smail:

```
dpkg-divert --package smailwrapper --add --rename \
    --divert /usr/sbin/smail.real /usr/sbin/smail
```

The --package smailwrapper ensures that smailwrapper’s copy of /usr/sbin/smail can bypass the diversion and get installed as the true version. It’s safe to add the diversion unconditionally on upgrades since it will be left unchanged if it already exists, but dpkg-divert will display a message. To suppress that message, make the command conditional on the version from which the package is being upgraded:

```
if [ upgrade != "$1 || dpkg --compare-versions "$2" lt 1.0-2; then
    dpkg-divert --package smailwrapper --add --rename \
        --divert /usr/sbin/smail.real /usr/sbin/smail
fi
```

where 1.0-2 is the version at which the diversion was first added to the package. Running the command during abort-upgrade is pointless but harmless.

The postrm has to do the reverse:

```
if [ remove = "$1" -o abort-install = "$1" -o disappear = "$1; then
    dpkg-divert --package smailwrapper --remove --rename \
        --divert /usr/sbin/smail.real /usr/sbin/smail
fi
```

If the diversion was added at a particular version, the postrm should also handle the failure case of upgrading from an older version (unless the older version is so old that direct upgrades are no longer supported):

```
if [ abort-upgrade = "$1 && dpkg --compare-versions "$2" lt 1.0-2; then
    dpkg-divert --package smailwrapper --remove --rename \
        --divert /usr/sbin/smail.real /usr/sbin/smail
fi
```

where 1.0-2 is the version at which the diversion was first added to the package. The postrm should not remove the diversion on upgrades both because there’s no reason to remove the diversion only to immediately re-add it and since the postrm of the old package is run after unpacking so the removal of the diversion will fail.

Do not attempt to divert a file which is vitally important for the system’s operation - when using dpkg-divert there is a time, after it has been diverted but before dpkg has installed the new version, when the file does not exist.

Do not attempt to divert a conffile, as dpkg does not handle it well.

Copy-pasted from debian wiki: https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ap-pkg-diversions.html